# JavaScript sorting after concat of two arrays now working

Tags: javascript

I've used a little function to concat two arrays and remove the duplicates:

```js
let a = ['06.12.2021', '07.12.2021', '19.12.2021', '20.12.2021', '01.03.2022', '03.03.2022', '06.12.2021', '09.01.2022'];
let b = ['17.11.2021', '04.01.2022', '08.01.2022', '09.01.2022'];

let ab = [...new Set( a.concat( b ) )];

console.log(ab);
```

This works quite nice, but actually they are in a complete bad order. At least, they should start with the lowest date and ends with the highest. I've tried a sort function without any success:

```js
let a = ['06.12.2021', '07.12.2021', '19.12.2021', '20.12.2021', '01.03.2022', '03.03.2022', '06.12.2021', '09.01.2022'];
let b = ['17.11.2021', '04.01.2022', '08.01.2022', '09.01.2022'];

let ab = [...new Set(a.concat(b))];

console.log(ab);

ab.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b) - Date.parse(a));

console.log(ab);
```

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Perhaps your sort function is sorting in reverse? Try `ab.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b));`

Comment: @dana Hm, actually the value `17.11.2021` is still nearly at the end

Comment: Take the simple step of logging your parsed dates – it is parsing them as `mm.dd.yyyy` so anything over 12 is NaN

Comment: The thing is default date format is `month.day.year`  thats why it breaks since it returns `NaN` for your dates

Comment: @pilchard Oh understand. Actually, I'm receiving the data from my PHP backend in the date format of the website because I want to use it within the Chart.js lib as labels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a custom `parse` function that parses dates explicitly formatted as `DD.MM.YYYY` into `Date` objects. This fixes the date parse issue. I also changed `b - a` to `a - b` which sorts in increasing order.

```js
let a = ['06.12.2021', '07.12.2021', '19.12.2021', '20.12.2021', '01.03.2022', '03.03.2022', '06.12.2021', '09.01.2022'];
let b = ['17.11.2021', '04.01.2022', '08.01.2022', '09.01.2022'];

let ab = [...new Set(a.concat(b))];

console.log(ab);

function parse(date) {
    const [d, m, y] = date.split('.');
    return new Date(y, m-1, d);
}

ab.sort((a, b) => parse(a) - parse(b));

console.log(ab);
```

Comment: `:` should have been `.`

Comment: hi @dana that is not unfortunately the correct order..

Comment: Also why convert back to a string? Date.parse is unreliable, you've taken the step to have all the components, just use them in `new Date`. (destructuring is also your friend when it comes to readalility) `const [d, m, y] = string.split('.'); const date = new Date(y, m-1, d);`

Comment: @pilchard - thanks for the nice tips in terms of formatting!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because some of the dates are not parseable in their current format and so can't be placed in the correct order. To test this yourself, try:

```js
let a = ['06.12.2021', '07.12.2021', '19.12.2021', '20.12.2021', '01.03.2022', '03.03.2022', '06.12.2021', '09.01.2022'];
let b = ['17.11.2021', '04.01.2022', '08.01.2022', '09.01.2022'];

let ab = [...new Set(a.concat(b))];

let test = ab.map(m => new Date(m))

console.log(test);
```

This is because JavaScript dates are not equipped for handling DD.MM.YYYY formatted dates. If you don't mind using a library, something like [DateJs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) may help

Answer (score 1):

With split() and sort() you can archive this:

```js
const a = ['06.12.2021', '07.12.2021', '19.12.2021', '20.12.2021', '01.03.2022', '03.03.2022', '06.12.2021', '09.01.2022'];
const b = ['17.11.2021', '04.01.2022', '08.01.2022', '09.01.2022'];

const ab = [...new Set( a.concat( b ) )];

const newDates = ab.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
}).map(e => {
  const a = e.split(".");
  return a[2] + "." + a[1] + "." + a[0]
}).sort().map(e => {
  const a = e.split(".");
  return a[2] + "." + a[1] + "." + a[0]
})

console.log('newDates',newDates)
```